# Auto select answer on Remote-Item powershell command

Tags: powershell

I automaticaly run simple powershell script: 
Remove-Item '\myserver\words.txt'
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGdhz.jpg)
And the problem is that I should to chose the Y or N e.t.c. Manually it is not bad, but I run my script automatically and I can't chose the answer manually.
How can I set "Y" answer automatically for remove-Item action?
Give please some examples. 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: `-Force -Confirm:$false`

Comment: Thanks! Now it's work for me: Remove-Item -recurse -force -confirm:$false '\myserver\words.txt'